# rg.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, pom.xml, camunda

I am new to Java and Maven/Spring. I am building a project to run a BPMN process in Camunda using a delegate. I have written the code, built the dependencies and am trying to build the project. When I put my JAR file into a Camunda container (I have Camunda deployed on a Linux server) I keep getting an error: **Unknown property used in expression: ${sqlDataRetrievalDelegate}. Cause: Cannot resolve identifier 'sqlDataRetrievalDelegate'**.

It seems to me that my Spring is not scanning and creating the Bin, what am I doing wrong? Help please.

Here's my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.camunda.bpm.getstarted</groupId>
    <artifactId>loan-approval-spring-boot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <camunda.spring-boot.version>7.19.0</camunda.spring-boot.version>
        <spring-boot.version>2.7.10</spring-boot.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <mssql.jdbc.version>9.2.1.jre11</mssql.jdbc.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.camunda.bpm.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter-webapp</artifactId>
            <version>${camunda.spring-boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${mssql.jdbc.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.myapp.sqlDataRetrievalDelegate</mainClass>
                    <layout>ZIP</layout>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Here's my JAVA code:

```
package com.myapp;

import org.camunda.bpm.engine.delegate.DelegateExecution;
import org.camunda.bpm.engine.delegate.JavaDelegate;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

@Component("sqlDataRetrievalDelegate")
public class sqlDataRetrievalDelegate implements JavaDelegate {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(sqlDataRetrievalDelegate.class);

    @Override
    public void execute(DelegateExecution execution) {
        logger.info("Executing SQL data retrieval delegate...");

        String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://10.100.11.11:1433;databaseName=DBtestData";
        String username = "camunda_sql1111";
        String password = "12345678";

        List<String> tags = Arrays.asList("MATR_TAG00001.SIM", "MATR_TAG00002.SIM", "MATR_TAG00003.SIM", "MATR_TAG00004.SIM");

        try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, username, password)) {
            String query = buildQuery(tags);

            try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query)) {
                try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        String tagName = rs.getString("TagName");
                        String timeStamp = rs.getString("TimeStamp");
                        double value = rs.getDouble("Value");

                        execution.setVariable("tagNameVariable", tagName);
                        execution.setVariable("timeStampVariable", timeStamp);
                        execution.setVariable("valueVariable", value);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Failed to execute SQL delegate", e);
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to execute SQL delegate", e);
        }
    }

    private String buildQuery(List<String> tags) {
        StringBuilder queryBuilder = new StringBuilder("SELECT TagName, TimeStamp, Value FROM OPENQUERY (PHD_OLEDB, 'SELECT * FROM phd.phd_data WHERE tagname IN (");
        for (int i = 0; i < tags.size(); i++) {
            queryBuilder.append("''").append(tags.get(i)).append("''");
            if (i < tags.size() - 1) {
                queryBuilder.append(",");
            }
        }
        queryBuilder.append(") AND raw_data = true')");

        return queryBuilder.toString();
    }
}
```

These are the logs I see in IDEA:

```
PS C:\Users\FilippovAn\untitled1> mvn -e spring-boot:run
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] --------< org.camunda.bpm.getstarted:loan-approval-spring-boot >--------
[INFO] Building loan-approval-spring-boot 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]   from pom.xml
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> spring-boot:2.7.10:run (default-cli) > test-compile @ loan-approval-spring-boot >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- resources:3.3.1:resources (default-resources) @ loan-approval-spring-boot ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1251 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 2 resources from src\main\resources to target\classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- compiler:3.11.0:compile (default-compile) @ loan-approval-spring-boot ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- resources:3.3.1:testResources (default-testResources) @ loan-approval-spring-boot ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1251 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\FilippovAn\untitled1\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- compiler:3.11.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ loan-approval-spring-boot ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< spring-boot:2.7.10:run (default-cli) < test-compile @ loan-approval-spring-boot <<<
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] --- spring-boot:2.7.10:run (default-cli) @ loan-approval-spring-boot ---
[INFO] Attaching agents: []
Error: Main method not found in class com.myapp.sqlDataRetrievalDelegate, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.102 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-08-18T11:30:12+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.7.10:run (default-cli) on project loan-approval-spring-boot: Application finished with exit code:
 1 -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.7.10:run (default-cli) on project loan-approval-s
pring-boot: Application finished with exit code: 1
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:333)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:906)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:206)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:283)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:226)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:407)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:348)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Application finished with exit code: 1
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.RunMojo.runWithForkedJvm (RunMojo.java:103)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo.doRunWithForkedJvm (AbstractRunMojo.java:291)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:255)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo.execute (AbstractRunMojo.java:225)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:906)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:206)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:283)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:226)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:407)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:348)
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

These are the logs I see in Camunda:

```
2023-08-15 12:15:02.465  WARN 10 --- [aTaskExecutor-3] org.camunda.bpm.engine.jobexecutor       : ENGINE14006 Exception while executing job acf3efa9-3b64-11ee-8bf4-0242ac120002:
org.camunda.bpm.engine.ProcessEngineException: Unknown property used in expression: ${sqlDataRetrievalDelegate}. Cause: Cannot resolve identifier 'sqlDataRetrievalDelegate'
```

Comment: This is the actual problem: "Error: Main method not found in class com.myapp.sqlDataRetrievalDelegate, please define the main method as:public static void main(String[] args)"

Comment: The camunda documentation says that you don't need to explicitly specify main in the code, and yes I tested with explicitly specifying it, but it didn't solve my problem, I think I have a bug somewhere in the code or pom, but I can't for the second week guess where...

Comment: Why is spring-boot-maven-plugin running in test phase?

Comment: I tried to run the process through the console to see if the class is scanned and the bin is created. maybe that's why?  This is my first time doing something like this and could be wrong, happy to hear suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your pom.xml in the configuration of the spring-boot-maven-plugin you specifiy you mainClass to be com.myapp.sqlDataRetrievalDelegate (by the way in Java the common practice is to start the class name with upper case so com.myapp.SqlDataRetrievalDelegate).

For a spring boot application you need an application class (see https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/).

So e.g. define the mainClass to be com.myapp.Application and that class should look like this:

```
package com.myapp;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

This will also enable the component scan and pick up your delegate bean.